# How to translate English into PigLatin with java (using boolean and string)

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I'm trying to write a program that checks a user supploed sentence and converts it to Pig Latin. I'm trying to have the program check to see if the first letter is a vowel or not and return that using a boolean expression. Next I'm trying to get the program to cut off the first letter from the word and add it to the end of the word. Finally its supposed to add `way` if it is a vowel and `ay` if it not a vowel.  Any help or advice will be greatly appreciated.

```
public class PigLatin     {
  public static void main(String[] argv) {
    if (argv.length > 0) {
      for (int i = 0; i < argv.length; i++) {
        char firstLetter = aStringVariable.charAt(0);
    }
  }
      public static boolean isVowel(char c) {
      char[] vowels = new char[] {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'y'};
        for(int i = 0; i < vowels.length; i++) {
            if(Character.toString(vowels[i]).equalsIgnoreCase(Character.toString(c)))  {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    public static String makePigLatin(boolean vowel, String word)
    {
      String everythingButTheFirstLetter = word.substring(1); 

      String n = everythingButTheFirstLetter + firstLetter;

    if (true)
    {
      System.out.println(n + "way");
    }
    if (false)
    {
      System.out.println(n + "ay");
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could clean up your indentations. Furthermore, what specific problem are you having? Are you getting an error or some unexpected output? What is your input?

Comment: It won't compile because of the line-  char firstLetter = aStringVariable.charAt(0);   I'm trying to see if someone knows how to change that to make it compile

Comment: `if (true)` will always be true, and `if (false)` will never be true.

Comment: Please mention the compilation error in the actual question, and please include the exact error message. You may want to revise the title to reflect this problem as well. As you're fairly new to StackOverflow, you might want read about [asking a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: this is the error: 
'Error: Syntax error on token "char", delete this token', however when i delete it is says "firstletter cannot be resolved to a variable' and "aStringVariable cannot be resolved"

Comment: You haven't declared `aStringVariable` anywhere.

Comment: Your formatting is so rough that everyone missed this fundamental error: you can't declare methods inside other methods. Take your isVowel() and makePigLatin() methods and move them outside your main() method, for a start.

Comment: @jpmc26 in addition, he seems to be missing a firstLetter variable. As for true always being true, I believe he was meant to write if (vowel == true) as opposed to if (true).

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this -

```
public static class PigLatin {
  public static boolean isVowel(char c) {
    switch (Character.toLowerCase(c)) {
    case 'a':
    case 'e':
    case 'i':
    case 'o':
    case 'u':
    case 'y':
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

  public static String makePigLatin(String word) {
    char firstLetter = word.charAt(0);
    String everythingElse = word.substring(1);

    String n = everythingElse + firstLetter;

    if (isVowel(firstLetter)) {
      return n + "way";
    }
    return n + "ay";
  }
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
  String[] words = { "fair", "away", "test" };
  for (String word : words) {
    String s = PigLatin.makePigLatin(word);
    System.out.println(word + " is " + s);
  }
}
```

Output is

```
fair is airfay
away is wayaway
test is esttay
```

Comment: Close.  The vowel test is on the first letter, not the second letter.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try something like:

```
  public static string PigLatin(string sentence)
    {
        const string vowels = "AEIOUaeiou";
        sentence = sentence.ToLower();
        var returnSentence = "";
        foreach (var word in sentence.Split())
        {
            var firstLetter = word.Substring(0, 1);
            var restOfWord = word.Substring(1, word.Length - 1);
            var currentLetter = vowels.IndexOf(firstLetter, StringComparison.Ordinal);

            if (currentLetter == -1)
            {
                returnSentence += restOfWord + firstLetter + "ay ";
            }
            else
            {
                returnSentence += word + "way ";
            }
        }
        returnSentence = returnSentence.TrimEnd();
        return returnSentence;
    }
```

The output for the sentence "The Quick Brown Fox Jumped Over The Lazy Dog" will be :

hetay uickqay rownbay oxfay umpedjay veroay hetay azylay ogday